# [SOLVED] How to subscribe a std_msgs::msg::String and copy in a std::string?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I'm having some issues in subscribing a topic containing `std_msgs::msg::string` on ros2 galactic. I have defined a `std::string` and want to subscribe the topic and do something like `string=msg.data. Here my code:

```
#include <memory>
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"
#include "kdl_parser/kdl_parser.hpp"
using std::placeholders::_1;

class ROBOT_INVDYN : public rclcpp::Node{
    public:
        ROBOT_INVDYN() : Node("robot_invdyn"){
        subscription_ = this->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String> ("robot_description", 10, std::bind(&ROBOT_INVDYN::topic_callback,this, _1));
        }
    private:
        std::string robot;
        void topic_callback(const std_msgs::msg::String &msg)const{
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I heard: '%s'", msg.data.c_str());
            robot=msg.data;
        }
        rclcpp::Subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>::SharedPtr subscription_; 
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
auto robot_node = std::make_shared<ROBOT_INVDYN>();
rclcpp::spin(robot_node);
rclcpp::shutdown();
return 0;
}
```

but I keep on receiving errors on the operator `=`as:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘const string’ {aka ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} and ‘const _data_type’ {aka ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’})
   17 |             robot_desc_string = msg.data;
      |                                     ^~~~
```

Could you help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412066/%5Bsolved%5D-how-to-subscribe-a-std_msgs::msg::string-and-copy-in-a-std::string?/) by [iopoi97](https://answers.ros.org/users/77786/iopoi97/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2023-01-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2023-01-31**:
Please share your complete code

**Comment by [iopoi97](https://answers.ros.org/users/77786/iopoi97/) on 2023-01-31**:
Yes, sure I will edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm pretty sure its because you marked your method signature as `const` but are modifying a non-const member variable `robot`. You should remove the `void topic_callback(const std_msgs::msg::String &msg) **const**`.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2023-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iopoi97](https://answers.ros.org/users/77786/iopoi97/) on 2023-02-01**:
perfect, it worked!

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2023-02-01**:
Can you mark this as the right answer with the checkmark so it is removed from the unanswered questions queue?

**Comment by [iopoi97](https://answers.ros.org/users/77786/iopoi97/) on 2023-02-02**:
Sorry for not having done this before!